# StoreKit2 for volume purchases

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit, storekit2

I am planning to convert a paid app to freemium. I would like existing paid users to remain unaffected in this process. In this question, I am focussing on volume purchase users (both existing and future). The info on Apple developer [website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/choosing_a_storekit_api_for_in-app_purchases) advises to use original Store Kit if one needs to support Volume Purchase users:

```
   You may need to use the Original API for in-app purchase for the following features,
   if your app supports them:


   The Volume Purchase Program (VPP). For more information, see Device Management.
```

Does that mean I can't use StoreKit2 to verify receipts of volume purchases made before the app went freemium (to get original purchase version and date), OR, the API can not be used to make in-app volume purchases and perhaps, users will not be able to make volume purchases from AppStore, OR, both?